# Server is not called while making an ajax post request in Django

Tags: django, ajax

Hey I am trying to implement a **like** feature on videos in django with the help of ajax. But when I click on the like icon then no request is made to server and which is not posting the data on the server. Thus like count remains unchanged.

More simply saying:

1. I am on the video detail page (which is for playing video and comments)
2. Now heading cursor over like button
3. After pressing like no change to likes count

When I see my terminal window then there is no request is made for like the video and as server is not contacted after pressing like then there is no change in likes counter. I am stuck over here and unable to find any solution to my problem. Below I am sharing few code snippets out of my project.

**views.py**

```
class DetailVideo(View):
def get(self, request, pk, *args, **kwargs):
    video = Video.objects.get(pk=pk)

    form = CommentForm()
    comments = Comment.objects.filter(video=video).order_by('-created_on')
    categories = Video.objects.filter(category=video.category)[:15]

    context = {
        'object': video,
        'comments': comments,
        'form': form,
        'categories': categories
    }
    return render(request, 'courses/detail_video.html', context)

def post(self, request, pk, *args, **kwargs):
    video = Video.objects.get(pk=pk)

    form = CommentForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        comment = Comment(
            user=self.request.user,
            comment=form.cleaned_data['comment'],
            video=video
        )
        comment.save()

    comments = Comment.objects.filter(video=video).order_by('-created_on')
    categories = Video.objects.filter(category=video.category)[:15]

    context = {
        'object': video,
        'comments': comments,
        'form': form,
        'categories': categories
    }
    return render(request, 'courses/detail_video.html', context)



class Like(View):
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.POST.get('action') == 'post' and request.is_ajax():
        result = ''
        pk = int(request.Post.get('videoid'))
        video = get_object_or_404(Video, pk = pk)
        if video.likes.filter(pk=request.user.pk).exsits():
            video.likes.remove(request.user)
            video.like_count -= 1
            result = video.like_count
            video.save()
        else:
            video.likes.add(request.user)
            video.like_count += 1
            result = video.like_count
            video.save()
        return JsonResponse({'result': result})
```

**urls.py**

```
app_name = "courses"

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.Index.as_view(), name = "home"),
    path('user-uploads/<str:username>', views.UserUploads.as_view(), name = "user-uploads"),
    path('create-video',  CreateVideo.as_view(), name='video-create'),
    path('<int:pk>/', DetailVideo.as_view(), name='video-detail'),
    path('<int:pk>/update-video', UpdateVideo.as_view(), name='video-update'),
    path('<int:pk>/delete-video', DeleteVideo.as_view(), name='video-delete'),
    path('category/<int:pk>', VideoCategoryList.as_view(), name='category-list'),
    path('search/', views.VideoSearch.as_view(), name='search-list'),
    path('like/', views.Like.as_view(), name='like'),
]
```

**script.js**

```
$(document).on('click', '#like-button', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '{% url "courses:like" %}',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {
    videoid: $('#like-button').val(),
    csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
    action: 'post'
  },
  success: function (json) {
    document.getElementById("like-count").innerHTML = json['result']
  },
  error: function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
    console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText);
  }  
});
});
```

**detail_video.html**

```
<h5 class="mt-4">{{ object.caption }}</h5>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 text-muted">
                    <p>{{ object.date_time | date:"M d, Y" }}</p>
                    <a class="category-link" href="{% url 'courses:category-list' object.category.pk %}">{{ object.category }}</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 text-muted text-right">
                    {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
                        <span class="" id="like-count">{{ object.like_count }}</span>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-outline-dark" id="like-button" value="{{ object.pk }}">
                            <ion-icon name="thumbs-up-sharp"></ion-icon>
                        </button>
                    {% endif %}
                    
                    
                </div>
            </div>
```

**models.py**

```
class Video(models.Model):
uploader = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
caption = models.CharField(max_length=100)
video_description = models.TextField()
video_file = models.FileField(upload_to="courses/video_files", validators=[FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=['mp4'])])
thumbnail = models.FileField(upload_to="courses/thumbnails", validators=[FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg'])])
date_time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
category = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='like', default='None', blank=True)
like_count = models.BigIntegerField(default='0')


def __str__(self):
    return self.caption
```

Comment: can you confirm if you have added the script src file for jquery. Also, what is the error you are getting in your browser's console while clicking on the like button?

Comment: I added it but after adding script inside the template it works otherwise it is not working. And there is no call made to server without any error

Comment: If it works after adding script to template, what is is the problem?

Comment: As of now problem is no more but was not able to implement the task by adding script from outside the html page